# How to update a same view (.jsp) using model.addAttributes ? | Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I would like to update a div in a .jsp page after submitting a form. So the flow would be like this:
Form submitted -> Ajax function called and point to url of a method of my controller -> Function processed and add new attribute to the model -> Return the same view. The problem is that the view does not update with the new attributes.

This is called after submitting.

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(){
    var search = $("#search-bar-input").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'search',
        method : 'get',
        data : {search : search},
        async : false,
        complete : function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
     });
})
```

Then it goes here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String search) {
   System.out.println(search);

   List<Film> films = filmJDBCTemplate.getFilmByName(search);

   model.addAttribute("films", films);     

   return "home";
}
```

Then, I noticed that it goes again in this function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayHome(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

// Display all genres
   List<Genre> listGenre = genreJDBCTemplate.listGenres();
   List<String> listGenreNom = new ArrayList<String>();

   for (Genre g : listGenre){
       listGenreNom.add(g.getNom());
   }

   model.addAttribute("listGenreNom", listGenreNom);

   String nom = accessData.getClient().getNomFamille() + " " + accessData.getClient().getPrenom();
   model.addAttribute("nom", nom);     
   return "home";
}
```

This is the part of the jsp page that should be updated.

```
<div id="movies-div">
    <c:forEach var="film" items="${films}">                 
        <div class="movie">
            <div class="poster-div">
                <img class="poster" src="${film.poster}" />
            </div>
            <div class="title-div">
                    ${film.titre}               
            </div>

        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

This is surely why my page is not updated. I've been looking for days how to resolve this problem but I couldn't find any similar cases to mine.

Please suggest me some ways to do that. Thanks a lot !

Comment: well you probably need to add some code in `complete : function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }`

Comment: so it is not possible to do it the way I did above ? I mean using mode.addAtributes("newAttribute", newAttribute) and returning the same view ?

Comment: I do not think so.  The JSP has already been rendered.  Is the correct data in `data.responseText` ?

Comment: `data.responseText` is undefined. Because I didn't return a response I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the return values with the data that you want to shown instead of the jsp name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String search) {
   System.out.println(search);

   List<Film> films = filmJDBCTemplate.getFilmByName(search);

   return films;
}
```